# How to fix the error "endDate.getDay is not a function"?

Tags: jquery

I am getting these errors in the Chrome console:

```
jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: endDate.getDay is not a function TypeError: endDate.getDay is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://www.example.it/wp-content/uploads/siteground-optimizer-assets/siteground-optimizer-combined-js-40bb2684c8af3cfe5929a54eeb793adf.js:12:48)
    at e (https://c0.wp.com/c/5.8.1/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js:2:30038)
    at t (https://c0.wp.com/c/5.8.1/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js:2:30340) undefined
S.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.min.js:2

jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: endDate.getDay is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (siteground-optimizer-combined-js-40bb2684c8af3cfe5929a54eeb793adf.js:11)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery.min.js:2)

jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: endDate.getDay is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (siteground-optimizer-combined-js-40bb2684c8af3cfe5929a54eeb793adf.js:12)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery.min.js:2)
```

I have several such functions in my functions.php file, which I use to show the delivery date of the services I offer on my website:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
  });
  if ($('body.page-id-5749').length > 0) {
    var monthNames = ["gennaio", "febbraio", "marzo", "aprile", "maggio", "giugno", "luglio", "agosto", "settembre", "ottobre", "novembre", "dicembre"];
    var dayNames = ["domenica", "lunedì", "martedì", "mercoledì", "giovedì", "venerdì", "sabato"];
    var holidays = [
      [2019, 12, 8], 8 DICEMBRE 2019[2019, 12, 25], 25 DICEMBRE 2019
    ];
    var endDate = "",
      noOfDaysToAdd = $(".val-mastering-basic").html(),
      count = 0;
    var someDate = new Date(new Date().toDateString());
    var numberOfDaysToAdd = noOfDaysToAdd;
    someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate());
    while (count < noOfDaysToAdd) {
      endDate = new Date(someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + 1));
      var isHoliday = holidays.find(holiday => endDate.getTime() == new Date(holiday[0], holiday[1] - 1, holiday[2]).getTime());
      if (isHoliday) {
        console.log('holiday, skipping');
      } else if (endDate.getDay() != 7 && endDate.getDay() != 8) { // 7 E 8 PER NON SALTARE WEEKEND, 0 e 6 PER SALTARLI
        count++;
      }
    }
    $('#date-mastering-basic').html(dayNames[endDate.getDay()] + ' ' + endDate.getDate() + ' ' + monthNames[endDate.getMonth()]);
  }
});
```

Comment: In the case that `noOfDaysToAdd` is not `>count` then `endDate===""` - given that `noOfDaysToAdd` is an *html string* it's a strange comparison.

Comment: Always debug what you actually have at the time of the error - in this case `console.log("[" + endDate+ "]")`  would give you `[]`

Comment: Depending on your requirement, you could possibly do: `var endDate = new Date(),` then you won't have the issue of setting `endDate` incorrectly to a *string*